# Ionic+Capacitor Push Notifications via Amazon SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ionic-framework, amazon-sns, capacitor

How to use Ionic+Capacitor to register Push Notifications via Amazon SNS

Any guide on how to properly use ionic and capacitor to acquire tokens for SNS? I’ve seen the PushNotifications plugin but I’m not sure what “register” does? Do i have to setup my firebase and apn if im only using Amazon SNS?

Any guide/tips or overview steps will be useful.

Thanks

Comment: yes you have to use Capacitor FCM plugin with Push notification plugin. and setup Device token from FCM and then you can use that token to your SNS service. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@capacitor-community/fcm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hoping this would help anyone starting their Ionic+Capactior + FCM/APN + Amazon SNS journey

Device Token Setup

1. Follow this guide: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/push-notifications-firebase. Follow all of them except all of the iOS Firebase ones (unless youre planning to use FCM to push to iOS as well)
2. Everytime the plugin runs, it should return a device token, log that or save that somewhere.

SNS Platform Setup

1. Feel free to follow any guide that teaches you how to create an FCM endpoint and an APNS endpoint. They're pretty straightforward, Cloud Messaging URL for FCM and a .p8 APNS key for iOS.

SNS Endpoint

1. Open your created platform application and Create a new endpoint, just chuck in the device token from the plugin. FCM and APNS have different token formats, APNS are mostly alphanumeric and all caps, while FCM are with special chars and mix of capital and small letters.

Of course this is just to establish a base point, I'm still working on trying to make them into services to actually push notifications via code. Good luck!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).